# How to add css class styles on button click in Angular?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, button, bootstrap-4

I have a **button which when clicked** , should **change the background colour** and the fint colours.Back to default when clicked again.So should change from light to dark mode.
The CSS classes are .bgdark and .textlight. These needs to added to the 'mainbody' for dark mode.

```
     HTML
    <div class="mainbody">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
     </div>
    TS

      export class AppComponent {
       title = 'salesapp';
           ngOnInit(){
                 }
                  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use binding to class names in order to dynamically add or remove them. You would implement the markup like so:

```html
<div class="mainbody" [class.bgnight]="haveClass">
    <button (click)="haveClass = !haveClass">Submit</button>
</div>
```

And your component would be like so:

```
export class AppComponent {
    haveClass = false;
}
```

Your button will toggle the `haveClass` boolean each time you click on it, which will add and remove the class from your div as expected.

Comment: Hi, thank you it has worked. If I have multiple class to bind, i can use ngClass. However how does it work with the click event?

Comment: If you want to get more complex you would just swap out the `click` handler for a function that does more complex logic. Basically each class is tied to a value on your component that is `true` or `false`, and you simply toggle those as needed.

Comment: Hi, can you please elaborate with code, will be helpful . Thanks